# When using flycheck, how to permanently disable pylint?

Tags: flycheck

I'm using Doom Emacs on macOS, if it matters.

Essentially, I'd like to disable the pylint checker entirely when editing Python files. I don't use pylint, and I don't have it installed in my Pyenv environments; it gives me false positives.

But I'm not a skilled Emacs user, and I can't figure out how to disable it. I have this in my config:

```el
(use-package! flycheck
  :config
  (add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-pylint)
  (add-hook 'pyhon-mode-local-vars-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (flycheck-may-enable-checker 'python-flake8)
              (flycheck-select-checker 'python-flake8)))))
```

But it doesn't seem to matter -- every time I open a Python file, it tries to start up pylint.

Comment: Have you checked `flycheck-disabled-checkers` explicitily to make sure it includes `python-pylint`? What happens if you do the `(add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-pylint)` by hand? Does flycheck skip it then?

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```el
(use-package flycheck
  :config
  (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(python-pylint)))
```

Comment: please add some reasoning to make your response more complete.

Comment: Yes, please let readers know how it answers the question - what it does.

Comment: This did not work on my end

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [flycheck docs](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checkers.html#disable-syntax-checkers) and the following worked, as suggested by the docs:

```
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(python-pylint))
```