# How can I completely disable all flycheck checkers such as pylint that works on the background?

Tags: flycheck

I want to disable memory hunger processes on the background, I believe it comes from flycheck. I have a 1GiB virtual machine where when `pylint` works on the background it consumes a lot of CPU, which freezes the machine.

[image]

At the end of my init.el file I have following function:

```lisp
(use-package flycheck
  :config
  (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(python-pylint)))
```

Which seems like did not help at all. I have remove all `flake8` lines in my init file but it still shows up.

How can I force to disable `python-pylint` or memory hunger `flycheck` processes?

Related: [When using flycheck, how to permanently disable pylint?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60936/when-using-flycheck-how-to-permanently-disable-pylint)

Comment: Do you use ```lsp```? if yes, what is the server in this case? Also I found out one question posted by you asking how to enable python-pylint (in 2020), maybe the reverse process?

Comment: Yes sir I am highly dependable using `lsp`; which allows me to jump into function definition and come back in Python. I can add my lsp setup into the question. I should find a way to use lsp as minimal as possible

Comment: IIRC, you setup ```pylint``` in your lsp configuration - is that correct? if yes, do not configure/modify flycheck, just disable pylint from lsp.

Comment: How can I disable pylint from lsp like the way I did in my question? // Yes there is `python-pylint` in the `lsp-managed-mode-hook` when I disable its `flake8` also shows up which consumes high memory as well

Comment: Verify your ```lsp``` configuration - you failed to tell what lsp server do you use - if ```pylsp``` then ```(setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-enabled nil)``` - or if you use ```pyright``` see there - take care this one scrap all your ```.py``` files and add watches to all those files, including ones for python package, may be some tens of thousands files. Another obvious solution is ```pip uninstall pylint```.

Comment: How can I check my which lsp server is used? I have `(require 'lsp-pylsp) (setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-enabled t)` I believe pylsp is used. Please note that I am not using `pyright`.

Comment: See this page: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/

Comment: For performance I have applied all advices here https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/ but it did not help much